# ModX wont work without absolute paths

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, wayfinder

I have built a site on Revo 2.1.3. All went well except for the site paths. Where I used to link to an image like:

```
assets/images/photo.jpg
```

It now wont work (appears as broken link) unless I put the complete path,e eg:

```
http://example.com/assets/images/photo.jpg
```

This isnt such a big deal changing the image paths, but it totally breaks Wayfinder.

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My templates were missing:

```
<base href="[[++site_url]]" />
```